# String is a substring of the second?

Tags: java, string, class, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I probably made a logical error somewhere but I do not know where.
The output is always FALSE even though the condition seem to be TRUE

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 ="Hello world";
    String str2 ="Hello world";

    if (checkSubstring(str1,str2)){
         System.out.println("Cool");
    }
    else 
         System.out.println("Not cool");
 }

 static boolean checkSubstring(String str1, String str2) {

    String s1 = str1;
    String s2 = str2;
    if (s1.substring(4)== s2.substring(4)){
      return true;  
    }
    else
    return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always use `equals` method to test for the content of `string`.

`==` operator checks whether two `reference` are pointing to same object or different ones. And since `s1.substring()` and `s2.substring()` will generate two different string objects, so comparing their `reference` will give you `false` boolean value.

So, in `checkSubstring` method, you should compare your substring like this: -

```
if (s1.substring(4).equals(s2.substring(4))) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @BlueBullet.. lol. was waiting for my target. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`s1.substring(4)== s2.substring(4)`

In the above Change it to `s1.substring(4).equals( s2.substring(4))`

**-** `Objects` in Java are compared using the `equals()` method.

**-** As `String` is an **Object in Java**, it must be treated in the same way.

**-** Moreover if you are trying to compare 2 String irrespective of their Case, then use `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

**-**  "==" is used for comparing the **primitive types**, and also to check whether 2 `Object Reference Variables` are **pointing on the same object on the heap or not.**

**Eg:**

```
Dog d1 = new Dog();
Dog d2 = d1;

if (d1 == d2){}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need equals function

```
static boolean checkSubstring(String str1, String str2) {

    String s1 = str1;
    String s2 = str2;
    if (s1.substring(4).equals(s2.substring(4))){
    return true;    
    }
    else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thank you guys/girls